# Show the information of group of points inside polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a packaged project file (ppkx) which contains group of points and polygons in ArcGIS Pro. The group of points all have attributes such as name, coordinates,... However, polygons do not. I want to link the information of polygons with points inside those polygons. Then, if I open the attribute table of those polygons, I could see the information of points inside (name, coordinates of all points). How could I do that?

Comment: This plan violates the fundamentals of relational theory. The points are not an attribute of the polygon (one-to-many); the polygon ID is an attribute of the points (many-to-one). In order to show the attributes of the many side you need to select from and display the *many* feature class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to display all the attributes of points inside the polygons when I use pop-up on those polygons, is it possible?